# My function works outside of the class but not from within the class

Tags: php

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I have a class as follows:

```
<?php

class files
{
public function getDirectoryList($directory)
{
    // create an array to hold directory list
    $results = array();

    // create a handler for the directory
    $handler = opendir($directory);

    // open directory and walk through the filenames
    while($file = readdir($handler)) 
    {

        // if the file isn't this directory or the parent, add it to the results.
        if($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            $results[] = $file;
        }
    }

    // tidy up: close the handler
    closedir($handler);

    //done
    return $results;
}
}

?>
```

Now I have the class included into another file and I'm doing the following:

```
$fileListing = new files();
$fileListing->getDirectoryList('education');
```

I'm not getting any results back. If I take the function out of the class and put it in this file, I can get results by doing:

```
$fileListing = getDirectoryList('education');
```

Comment: Are you returning the class method call into a variable, as you are in the second example?

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code, check what `var_dump( $fileListing->getDirectoryList('education') )` tells you.

Comment: if you want to print out the result, use 'echo $results' in your function, otherwise assign to variable, like suggested by @JaredFarrish

Comment: Have you tried passing absolute paths in the two versions of the code, just to make sure this is not related to relative paths?

Comment: Sheesh.... I completely spaced on assigning it to a variable. Using `$myfiles = $fileListing->getDirectoryList('education');` worked. I just wasn't seeing that. Thanks Jared and Dirk.